# Convert degrees value to units from 0 to 100

Tags: javascript, math

I have a component that returns me a value from 0 to 360 degrees, I need to pass that value to units, for example from 0 to 100.

I have the following function but it seems ugly

```
function degToValue( deg ) 
{
    var unit = Math.ceil( ( deg * 100 ) / 360 );
    if ( unit ===  0 ) unit = 100;
    if ( deg < 1.6 && deg > 0 ) unit = 0;
    return unit;
}
```

Do you know a more elegant way?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also known as "gradian": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian

Comment: Except that a gradian would be 0 to 400, not 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide by `3.6` and use modulus to make this much prettier:

```
function degToValue( deg )
{
    var unit = (deg / 3.6) % 100;
    return (unit === 0 ? 100 : unit);
}

console.log( degToValue( 360 )); //100
console.log( degToValue( 0 )); //100
console.log( degToValue( 355 )); //98.61
console.log( degToValue( 719 )); //99.72
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this way never show the 0 value.

Comment: This is the problem. The same degrees value can't have two different values. Therefore my ugly conditions. In any case your method is much prettier!

Comment: @eledgaar The same degree value will always have the same value. `360` is 0, because it automatically gets modulus'd by `100`. `359` would giv e`99.72` just like `719`.